# getting window error when using emoji-mart on Next.js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, emoji, picker

I want to use emoji-mart package in my next js application. Here is the error in localhost

**`ReferenceError: window is not defined`**

`file:///C:/Users/../node_modules/emoji-mart/dist/main.js (1667:47)`

I tried to  install the package in a simple react app and it worked as normal. I guess the error in localhost is about next js

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Next.js is attempting to resolve `emoji-mart` on the server side, where there is no `window` object available. You can try using a dynamic import to help solve the issue:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const Picker = dynamic(
  () => import('emoji-mart'),
  { ssr: false }
)
```

Here are the official docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I tried dynamic import too and  got the error below:                                                                                                                           Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.                                              It might be that I am tring to import a component from a 3rd party library.